# Multiple requests with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

i have implemented example from this link
[Multiple requests with retrofit to combine results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJb3O.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJb3O.png): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38114462/2024338 , but at my side throws this exception, can anyone suggest me solution for this?

Error Screenshot[image]

Comment: use BiFunction instead Func2 or in java 8
third parameter would (jsonObject,jsonelement,dbManager)->{ }

Answer (score 1):

You use RxJava2 ? Because Func2 is now replaced by BiFunction.

Comment: thanks, but i can`t find any good example to understan the syntax and code , can you please provide some useful inks?

Comment: You can find an example here https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples/blob/12e21f0e7b1a569e093c9a04ed1098fb6b218237/app/src/main/java/com/rxjava2/android/samples/ui/operators/ScanExampleActivity.java#L48